# mutate to create new columns with max and mins from other columns by group

Tags: r, dplyr, max, min, mutate

Say my dataset has two columns

```
A = c(1,5,NA,NA,NA)
B = c(NA,NA,10,11,13)
```

how do I create a new column C that takes the max value from A and the min from B to create a new column:

```
C= c(NA,5,10,NA,NA)
```

Comment: Good catch, they should all have 5 entries. I've corrected it.

Comment: The max of A should be the max of that column ignoring NAs. The min of B should be the min of B ignoring NAs.

Comment: What happens if the max of A has the same position as the min of B?

Comment: Allan, I made a mistake and updated the question. But, in this df, columns A and B never have values in the same rows. The new column is intended to bridge that. I'm basically trying to create a plot with lots of geom_lines and this column is indended to create a line connecting the last observation from column A to the first obervation in column B. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: hks, you momentarily had a comment for me in your question indicating you wanted indices instead of values ... and now you've reversed that comment. Is it as it should be? I'm a little confused ... (and perhaps comments like that belong as comments under the answer to which they apply ...)

Comment: Thanks rkevans. I did edit my original question when I realised I made a mistake but I wasn't sure if people would see it. Also, it occurred to me that it would be more helpful for other people searching if I posted the different questions separately. I had to wait for 90 minutes to post the new question but just did so. I really appreciate your help, I've been hitting walls with this for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, if `which.max(A) == which.min(B)`, then `A` wins ... that can be changed by swapping the order within `case_when` or reversing the nesting of the base R `ifelse`s.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  mutate(
    C2 = case_when(
      row_number() == which.max(A) ~ A, 
      row_number() == which.min(B) ~ B, 
      TRUE ~ NA)
  )
#    A  B  C C2
# 1  1 NA NA NA
# 2  5 NA  5  5
# 3 NA 10 10 10
# 4 NA 11 NA NA
# 5 NA 13 NA NA
```

## base R

(I don't really like nested `ifelse`, but this is uncomplicated ...)

```r
with(quux, ifelse(seq_along(A) == which.max(A), A,
                  ifelse(seq_along(A) == which.min(B), B, NA)))
# [1] NA  5 10 NA NA
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(A = c(1, 5, NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, NA, 10, 11, 13), C = c(NA, 5, 10, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

<sup>*(P.S.: if you know all numbers will be effectively integer, then you can shorten this a little by replacing `seq_along(A) == which.max(A)` with `A == max(A)`, etc. The reason I don't *start* with that is that floating-point equality is imperfect in the presence of high-precision numbers, see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272) and https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f.)*</sup>

Comment: I can't vote up yet but this was really helpful - did exactly what I thought I wanted to do and clarified for me that it is not, actually, what I need to do.

Comment: (In fact, you should really go to all of your [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20542491/hks?tab=questions) with answers and accept for each of them as well.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm new, still learning. I'll do that right now.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could also do:

```
replace(rep(NA, length(A)), 
         c(i1<-which.min(B), i2<-which.max(A)), c(B[i1], A[i2]))
[1] NA  5 10 NA NA
```

---

We could break this down as:

```
C <- rep(NA, length(A))
i1 <- which.min(B)
i2 <- which.max(A)
C[c(i1,i2)] <- c(B[i1], A[i2])
C
[1] NA  5 10 NA NA
```